# Get country name in jVectorMap - React

Tags: reactjs

In React, how do you get the value of a country and assign to an input when a country is clicked in jVectorMap?

Map:

```
<div className="col-md-7">
   <div id="audience-map" className="vector-map"></div>
        <VectorMap
          map={"world_mill"}
          backgroundColor="transparent"
          panOnDrag={true}
          containerClassName="dashboard-vector-map"
            focusOn= { {
             x: 0.5,
             y: 0.5,
             scale: 1,
             animate: true
           }}
           series={{
             regions: [{
                scale: ['#3d3c3c', '#f2f2f2'],
                normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
                values: mapData
             }]
           }}
      />
</div>
```

Input to be populated when a country is clicked:

```
 <div className="form-group">
   <select className="form-control form-control-lg" id="exampleFormControlSelect2">
     <option>Country</option>
     <option>United States of America</option>
     <option>United Kingdom</option>
     <option>India</option>
     <option>Germany</option>
     <option>Argentina</option>
     <option>Kenya</option>
     <option>Nigeria</option>
     <option>South Africa</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the name of the country selected like this:

```
<div className="col-md-7">
   <div id="audience-map" className="vector-map"></div>
        <VectorMap
          map={"world_mill"}
          backgroundColor="transparent"
          panOnDrag={true}
          containerClassName="dashboard-vector-map"
          onRegionClick={(e, countryCode) => this.setState({ countryCode: countryCode})}
            focusOn= { {
             x: 0.5,
             y: 0.5,
             scale: 1,
             animate: true
           }}
           series={{
             regions: [{
                scale: ['#3d3c3c', '#f2f2f2'],
                normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
                values: mapData
             }]
           }}
      />
</div>
```